# Selenium JavascriptExecutor - Unexpected token at javascript algorithm

Tags: java, selenium

I try to execute this java code

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement hoverElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id = 'demo']")));

//trigger mouseover on hoverElement
//return innerHTML of element which appear
String jsAlg = "" +
    "if(document.createEvent){" +
        "var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');" +
        "evObj.initEvent('mouseover', true, false);" +
        "arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evObj);" +
    "}else if(document.createEventObject){" +
        "arguments[0].fireEvent('onmouseover');" +
    "}" +
    "var target = new XPathEvaluator().createExpression(//div[@id = 'target'])" +
                                        ".evaluate(document, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE)" +
                                        ".singleNodeValue" +
    "return target.innerHTML;";

String targetHTML = (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(jsAlg, hoverElement);

System.out.println(targetHTML);
```

I try to execute this js on this html

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="demo" onmouseover="mouseOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()">Mouse over here</div>

        <script>

            var node = document.createElement("div");
            node.id = "target";
            node.innerHTML = "mouse over active";

            function mouseOver() {
              document.body.appendChild(node);
            }

            function mouseOut() {
              document.body.removeChild(node);
            }

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

I get an error when try to execute `jsAlg`: `javascript error: Unexpected token '}'`

What is wrong at `jsAlg`?

**Edit 1**

The problem is at `var target = ...`.

I replaced that with `var target = document.getElementById('target');` and work.

But I need to use `XPathEvaluator` because, I execute this `js` in other case, where `target` don't have an `id` and can identify it with xpath.

**Edit 2(I found the real problem)**

The problem was at `.createExpression(//div[@id = 'target'])`

It should be `.createExpression(\"//div[@id = 'target']\")`

Parameter should be between `"`

Comment: the WebElement object is probably causing this.  Try passing in the ID instead and then get the element in the javascript you are executing.

Comment: @pcalkins You say to change `arguments[0]` with `document.getElementById("demo")` and no longer passing `hoverElement` as argument in `executeScript` ? I tried this and same error.

Comment: @pcalkins I found the source of problem. It is at `var target = ...` . Look at edit1, but I still don't know how to fix it.

Comment: ah ha... didn't see that.  Quotes for the xpath.  So WebElement does work fine as an arg?

Comment: @pcalkins Sure, it works fine